# How to destroy the slimScroll only from parent not from children

Tags: slimscroll

I would like to destroy the `slimScroll` with the following condition, it works fine.

But the issue is this is removing the all `slimScroll` objects from the children too.

so, parent and children all are destroyed, how to avoid that?

Here is my condition, I am not using the `id` I using the `class` selector here.

```
if(this.spaceFinder(this.clippings)  < this.clippings.innerHeight() ) {
    this.clippings.slimScroll({destroy:true});
    //remove from all childrens too..
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6q58tf9/32/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way, and it works!

```
var container = $('.container');
var para = $('.textInfo');
$('#add').click(function () {
    var textarea = $('<textarea />');
    textarea.text(para.text());
    textarea.appendTo('.container');
    textarea.slimScroll({height:'50px'});

    if(container[0].scrollHeight > 300) {
        container.slimScroll({height:'200px'});
    }
});
$('#remove').click(function () {
    $('textarea').first().slimScroll({destroy:true});
    $('textarea').first().remove();

    if(container[0].scrollHeight < 300) {
        var children = $('#container').children();
        $('#container').parent().replaceWith($('#container'));
    }
});
```

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/L6q58tf9/33/)

Answer (score 0):

@3gwebtrain, I made a fix to the plugin.

I made a pull request: https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/pull/193

And the fix is simple if you want to change your jquery.slimscroll.js file. You can view modiffications made here: https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/pull/193/files